# different development/production databases in scalaquery

Tags: database, scala, scalaquery

ScalaQuery requires (AFAIK) to use an provider specific import in your code, for example:

```
import org.scalaquery.ql.extended.H2Driver.Implicit._
```

We are trying to use H2 in development mode and MySQL in production. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

My approach was:

```
class Subscribers(database: Database)(profile: ExtendedProfile) {
    import profile.Implicit._
}
```

Where Subscribers basically is my Data-Access-Object.
Not sure this is the best approach out there. It solved my case.

You would create such DAO like:

...in production code:

```
new Subscribers(database)(MySQLDriver)
```

...and in test code:

```
new Subscribers(database)(H2Driver)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the following in playframework

```
object test {
  lazy val extendedProfile = {
    val extendedProfileName = Play.configuration getString "db.default.extendedProfile" get
    companionObjectNamed(extendedProfileName).asInstanceOf[ExtendedProfile]
  }

  def companionObjectNamed(name: String) : AnyRef = {
    val c = Class forName (name + "$")
    c.getField("MODULE$") get c
  }
}
```

And then import

```
import util.extendedProfile.Implicit._
```

`org.scalaquery.ql.extended.MySQLDriver` is the string I used in config to make mysql work.